# How to efficiently get matrix of the desired form in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have four numpy arrays like:

```
X1 = array([[1, 2], [2, 0]])

X2 = array([[3, 1], [2, 2]])

I1 = array([[1], [1]])

I2 = array([[1], [1]])
```

And I'm doing:

```
Y = array([I1, X1],
          [I2, X2]])
```

To get:

```
Y = array([[ 1,  1,  2],
           [ 1,  2,  0],
           [-1, -3, -1],
           [-1, -2, -2]])
```

Like this example, I have large matrices, where `X1` and `X2` are `n x d` matrices.

Is there an efficient way in Python whereby I can get the matrix `Y`?

Although I am aware of the iterative manner, I am searching for an efficient manner to accomplish the above mentioned.

Here, `Y` is an `n x (d+1)` matrix and `I1` and `I2` are identity matrices of the dimension `n x 1`.

Comment: What type have your matrices, are they nested lists?

Comment: @Mihail I have writing the dimensions of matrices. The matrices are not nested. Thanks for replying

Comment: I think @Mihail was asking if those are numpy array. In any case could you paste a runnable example (maybe an interactive session extract, with `Y = numpy.array([ ...`).

Comment: @Rik Poggi yes X1 and X2 are numpy arrays

Comment: @user869790: I tried to improve your question, please fix whatever I may have misunderstood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [numpy.bmat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html)

```
In [4]: A = np.mat('1 ; 1 ')
In [5]: B = np.mat('2 2; 2 2')
In [6]: C = np.mat('3 ; 5')
In [7]: D = np.mat('7 8; 9 0')
In [8]: np.bmat([[A,B],[C,D]])
Out[8]: 
matrix([[1, 2, 2],
        [1, 2, 2],
        [3, 7, 8],
        [5, 9, 0]])
```

Comment: +1 - hadn't seen this before. It also works for arrays, although it outputs a numpy matrix rather than array. nice work.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: X1 = np.array([[1,2],[2,0]])

In [3]: X2 = np.array([[3,1],[2,2]])

In [4]: I1 = np.array([[1],[1]])

In [5]: I2 = np.array([[4],[4]])

In [7]: Y = np.vstack((np.hstack((I1,X1)),np.hstack((I2,X2))))

In [8]: Y
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [4, 3, 1],
       [4, 2, 2]])
```

Alternatively you could create an empty array of the appropriate size and fill it using the appropriate slices. This would avoid making intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

For a `numpy` `array`, [this page](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) suggests the syntax may be of the form

```
vstack([hstack([a,b]),
        hstack([c,d])])
```